# How to load content pages asynchrously from the click on layout page link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am working on Asp.net mvc. I have a legacy layout page that contains left pane and center pane(content pane) i.e. my left pane contains some tabs like home, events etc. when the user clicks on any tab the respective action will takes place and the page is loaded. but i want to 
load the content pane asynchronously i.e. without loading the entire page i.e both layout and content pages i just want to load the content page only. for that i have used jquery ajax calls and RenderPartial views mechanism like,

```
$('#lnkHome').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Home',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('div.ContentPane').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
public actionresult Home()
{
return Partial("_home");
}
```

But i am unable to use all my javascript code i think it is overlapped with layout page scripts. Does there any way to load the pages asyncornously that match to my scenario. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

If those links are anchors you should ensure to cancel the default event by returning false from the click handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menuLink').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('div.ContentPane').html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Now you could have many links in your left pane:

```
@Html.ActionLink("go to home", "index", "home", null, new { @class = "menuLink" })
@Html.ActionLink("go to events", "events", "home", null, new { @class = "menuLink" })
...
```

or simply use Ajax.ActionLinks:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("go to home", "index", "home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "contentPane", HttpMethod = "POST" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("go to events", "events", "home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "contentPane", HttpMethod = "POST" })
...
```

You just need to give an id to your content pane id because the Ajax.ActionLink expects an id for the target DOM element:

```
<div id="contentPane">
    ...
</div>
```

and don't forget to reference the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` script in your page in order for Ajax.ActionLinks to actually be unobtrusively AJAXified and send AJAX requests instead of regular requests:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```